# How to get WPF window close button design?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image

I want to use the Close button as it shown in WPF windows application into my application.
Is it possible to get the design/image from the existing resources? Anyone points to me to get Pressed, Normal and Hover icons for close?. I could not get them all in one place to match each other..

I have attached  close button image here..

[image]

Comment: I doubt it's possible - I'm sure it's a protected embedded resource. However, I'm equally sure that some free icon site out there has a very close match to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That part of the window, termed the chrome, is not rendered by the WPF framework. You can create a chromeless window and render you own chrome. There are quite a few articles / blogposts that describe this. For example:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx

If you just want the images, try a screen capture tool.